# Dart map to another map through map function

Tags: dart

Suppose I have a Map:

```
Map<String, int> source = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3};
```

I want to get this:

```
Map<String, int> expected = {'a': 1, 'b':4, 'c':9 };
```

I want to achieve the result using map function:

```
Map<String,int> actual = source.map((key,value)=> {key: value * value});
```

However, I got this error:

```
The return type 'Map<String, int>' isn't a 'MapEntry<String, int>', as required by the closure's context
```

Can't we use the map function of map to get another map like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mapping method should return a MapEntry instance since you can change both the key and value. So your code should instead be something like:

```
void main() {
  final source = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3};
  final actual = source.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value * value));
  print(actual); // {a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using collection-for might be more straightforward than using `Map.map`:

```dart
final source = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3};
final actual = {
  for (var entry in source.entries)
    entry.key: entry.value * entry.value,
};
```